# Rijndael decryption in WinRT

Tags: c#, encryption, windows-runtime, aes

I'm trying to write a method that decrypts a byte array.

- the key is **fixed** and **24 bytes** long

I get an exception `The supplied user buffer is not valid for the requested operation` when I do the actual decryption of the data, I hope someone can help me!

```
        // Get the key and put into IBuffers

        IBuffer keyBuffer = CryptographicBuffer.CreateFromByteArray(cKey);
        IBuffer plainText = CryptographicBuffer.CreateFromByteArray(cData);
        byte[] decryptedData;

        // Setup an AES key, using AES in CBC mode and applying PKCS#7 padding on the input
        SymmetricKeyAlgorithmProvider aesProvider = SymmetricKeyAlgorithmProvider.OpenAlgorithm(SymmetricAlgorithmNames.AesEcbPkcs7);
        CryptographicKey aesKeySymm = aesProvider.CreateSymmetricKey(keyBuffer);


        // Decrypt the data and convert it to byte array

        // EXCEPTION ON THIS LINE: "The supplied user buffer is not valid for the requested operation."
        IBuffer decrypted = CryptographicEngine.Decrypt(aesKeySymm, plainText, null);
        CryptographicBuffer.CopyToByteArray(decrypted, out decryptedData);
        return decryptedData;
```

Comment: I've edited your question to make the actual exception you're receiving more obvious, please take note :)

Answer (score 0):

CBC requires an IV (also a an `IBuffer` for `CryptographicEngine.encrypt` and `CryptographicEngine.decrypt`, so you cannot provide `null`. This is only written down for the [`encrypt` function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows.security.cryptography.core.cryptographicengine.encrypt.aspx) that the `decrypt` function references.